Rabbitmq STOMP direct exchange using docker compose, AWS EC2, spring boot
hi i'm koeran student and i got a problem while developing 1:1 chatting.
I spent almost a week to try to solve the problem, but ultimately couldn't resolve it.
let me show you the problem i got.
I've deployed a total of 4 containers on an EC2 instance using Docker Compose (spring boot, redis, rabbitmq, postgresql). The inbound rule of the instance has been opened for port 8080, and currently, an Elastic IP address is assigned to the instance.
After connecting to the EC2 instance and installing all necessary modules, including Docker Compose, and running the build and docker-compose commands, all containers are functioning correctly.
However, when trying to test the STOMP connection on an APIC website, it fails to connect to the endpoint ("/ws" -> "ws://{EC2 public IP Address}/ws") I configured.
I think the reason why the Stomp connection is not working is because of the dockers' port forwarding incorrect. Could you please check if the docker-compose.yml ports and application codes are configured correctly?
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StompConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.host}")
    private String rabbitmqHost; // localhost

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.username}")
    private String rabbitmqUsername; // guest

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.password}")
    private String rabbitmqPassword; // guest

    private final ChatAuthInterceptor chatAuthInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
                // .withSockJS();
    }

    // STOMP 에서 사용하는 메세지 브로커 설정
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue", "/topic", "/exchange", "/amq/queue") // 구독 url

                .setClientLogin(rabbitmqUsername) // guest
                .setClientPasscode(rabbitmqPassword) // guest

                .setSystemLogin(rabbitmqUsername) // guest
                .setSystemPasscode(rabbitmqPassword) // guest

                .setRelayHost(rabbitmqHost) // localhost
                .setRelayPort(61613)

                .setVirtualHost("/");

        registry.setPathMatcher(new AntPathMatcher("."));
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/pub"); // 발행 url
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(chatAuthInterceptor);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitConfig {

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.host}")
    private String rabbitmqHost; // localhost

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.port}")
    private int rabbitmqPort; // 5672

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.username}")
    private String rabbitmqUsername; // guest

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.password}")
    private String rabbitmqPassword; // guest

    @Value("${rabbitmq.queue.name}")
    private String queueName; // chat.queue

    @Value("${rabbitmq.exchange.name}")
    private String exchangeName; // chat.exchange

    @Value("${rabbitmq.routing.key}")
    private String routingKey; // room.* (* will be replaced by member's id)

    // Queue 등록
    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, true);
    }

    // Exchange 등록
    @Bean
    public DirectExchange directExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(exchangeName, true, false, null);
    }

    // Exchange 와 Queue 바인딩
    @Bean
    public Binding binding(Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(routingKey);
    }

    // MessageConverter 커스텀을 위해 Bean 새로 등록
    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        rabbitTemplate.setRoutingKey(routingKey);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    // 스프링이 자동 주입하는 ConnectionFactory 사용하지 않기 위함
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory factory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost(rabbitmqHost);
        factory.setPort(rabbitmqPort);
        factory.setUsername(rabbitmqUsername);
        factory.setPassword(rabbitmqPassword);
        return factory;
    }

    // LocalDateTime serialize 를 위해
    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
        objectMapper.registerModule(dateTimeModule());

        Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapper);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public Module dateTimeModule() {
        return new JavaTimeModule();
    }
}

I'll show you the logs of each container.
[sudo docker ps]

rabbitmq container
    2024-04-29 08:38:40.025347+00:00 [info] <0.648.0> Management plugin: HTTP (non-TLS) listener started on port 15672
    2024-04-29 08:38:40.025635+00:00 [info] <0.676.0> Statistics database started.
    2024-04-29 08:38:40.025769+00:00 [info] <0.675.0> Starting worker pool 'management_worker_pool' with 3 processes in it
    2024-04-29 08:38:40.047349+00:00 [info] <0.689.0> rabbit_stomp: default user 'guest' enabled
    2024-04-29 08:38:40.049616+00:00 [info] <0.708.0> started STOMP TCP listener on [::]:61613
    2024-04-29 08:38:40.053926+00:00 [info] <0.712.0> Prometheus metrics: HTTP (non-TLS) listener started on port 15692
    2024-04-29 08:38:40.054244+00:00 [info] <0.589.0> Ready to start client connection listeners
    2024-04-29 08:38:40.058245+00:00 [info] <0.756.0> started TCP listener on [::]:5672
     completed with 5 plugins.
    2024-04-29 08:38:40.265093+00:00 [info] <0.589.0> Server startup complete; 5 plugins started.
    2024-04-29 08:38:40.265093+00:00 [info] <0.589.0>  * rabbitmq_prometheus
    2024-04-29 08:38:40.265093+00:00 [info] <0.589.0>  * rabbitmq_stomp
    2024-04-29 08:38:40.265093+00:00 [info] <0.589.0>  * rabbitmq_management
    2024-04-29 08:38:40.265093+00:00 [info] <0.589.0>  * rabbitmq_management_agent
    2024-04-29 08:38:40.265093+00:00 [info] <0.589.0>  * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
    2024-04-29 08:38:40.390590+00:00 [info] <0.9.0> Time to start RabbitMQ: 12773511 us
    2024-04-29 08:38:42.569849+00:00 [info] <0.760.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.760.0> (172.20.0.5:40836 -> 172.20.0.2:5672)
    2024-04-29 08:38:42.638746+00:00 [info] <0.760.0> connection <0.760.0> (172.20.0.5:40836 -> 172.20.0.2:5672) has a client-provided name: connectionFactory#42130a5c:0
    2024-04-29 08:38:42.646383+00:00 [info] <0.760.0> connection <0.760.0> (172.20.0.5:40836 -> 172.20.0.2:5672 - connectionFactory#42130a5c:0): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
    2024-04-29 08:38:43.272630+00:00 [info] <0.781.0> accepting STOMP connection <0.781.0> (172.20.0.5:54648 -> 172.20.0.2:61613)
    2024-04-29 08:38:43.342459+00:00 [warning] <0.781.0> AMQP 0-9-1 client call timeout was 70000 ms, is updated to a safe effective value of 130000 ms


spring boot container
2024-04-29T18:09:42.527+09:00  INFO 1 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[1 sessions, ReactorNettyTcpClient[reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientConnect@18a129b8] (available), processed CONNECT(1)-CONNECTED(1)-DISCONNECT(0)], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 2, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
2024-04-29T18:39:42.528+09:00  INFO 1 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[1 sessions, ReactorNettyTcpClient[reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientConnect@18a129b8] (available), processed CONNECT(1)-CONNECTED(1)-DISCONNECT(0)], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 2, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2]
2024-04-29T19:09:42.529+09:00  INFO 1 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[1 sessions, ReactorNettyTcpClient[reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientConnect@18a129b8] (available), processed CONNECT(1)-CONNECTED(1)-DISCONNECT(0)], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 2, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 3]
2024-04-29T19:39:42.529+09:00  INFO 1 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[1 sessions, ReactorNettyTcpClient[reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientConnect@18a129b8] (available), processed CONNECT(1)-CONNECTED(1)-DISCONNECT(0)], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 2, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 4]
2024-04-29T20:09:42.530+09:00  INFO 1 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[1 sessions, ReactorNettyTcpClient[reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientConnect@18a129b8] (available), processed CONNECT(1)-CONNECTED(1)-DISCONNECT(0)], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 2, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 5]
2024-04-29T20:39:42.530+09:00  INFO 1 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[1 sessions, ReactorNettyTcpClient[reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientConnect@18a129b8] (available), processed CONNECT(1)-CONNECTED(1)-DISCONNECT(0)], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 2, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 6]


i omit postgresql container log, redis container log.
here are some capture image testing STOMP connection in APIC website

[APIC website testing STOMP connection]

[rabbitmq admin page]

docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  database:
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: facefriend-db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS=--encoding=UTF-8
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
    expose:
      - ${DB_PORT}
    ports:
      - ${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ./db/initial_setup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initial_setup.sql
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/


  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
      - rabbitmq
    links:
      - database
      - redis
      - rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    image: facefriend-app
    container_name: facefriend-app
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://database:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}

      SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_PORT: 5672
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_USERNAME: guest
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD: guest

      SPRING_REDIS_HOST: redis
      SPRING_REDIS_PORT: 6379


  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    command: redis-server --port 6379
    container_name: facefriend_redis
    labels:
      - "name=redis"
      - "mode=standalone"
    ports:
      - 6379:6379


  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.12.11-management
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: facefriend_rabbitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER = guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS = guest
      - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE = OJUZRGYJJNHYNJLZTPCM
    command: [
      "bash", "-c",
      "chmod 400 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie; 
      rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management;
      rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_stomp;
      rabbitmq-server" ]

volumes:
  postgres_data:



sudo docker network ls (in ec2 console)
NETWORK ID     NAME                       DRIVER    SCOPE
1b05fee98563   bridge                     bridge    local
3baf5b068c80   capstone-2024-18_default   bridge    local
ae4170e940d5   host                       host      local
3b29ea965211   none                       null      local



sudo docker network inspect 3baf5b068c80 (in ec2 console)
[
    {
        "Name": "capstone-2024-18_default",
        "Id": "3baf5b068c806f920fc421ef9666170e1f048908e54de3a2a3c3fcb54e797682",
        "Created": "2024-04-30T03:49:15.658436017Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.23.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.23.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "874f911322cbb684879101ad8d2105134dc40f41b6515c12635421cf1be27f50": {
                "Name": "facefriend-db",
                "EndpointID": "c522f1eeed500bb36257e6f579c210550e495379cbcc50c62d14a24e2cac0990",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "d84dc11c46bf83c159d1fb8a535ceddb7ff064df567a371c4cd778f080e2e12f": {
                "Name": "facefriend_redis",
                "EndpointID": "a77951de30b8b27775c31e8a24653b8d522f502919c30099c6c590b28677feab",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "d9311bb33f8404e7b675dff854077c792c9a7ea956c5f5837b746e7aa201f033": {
                "Name": "facefriend_rabbitmq",
                "EndpointID": "ad91df37f4c617ee8db02d254fe2d9391d47966782686e1e7cc96f24e68f86d7",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ee6a219a2c8b6f8ff4d1827a13d6184bcb2e01115a7b8233c5c01903170ef222": {
                "Name": "facefriend-app",
                "EndpointID": "8500d61840f883b39be9b9f7ce8d9c5664322b1e5f58c12f9747e3d852ca9827",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "capstone-2024-18",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.5.0"
        }
    }
]

